# How to edit JSON files in batch?

Tags: json, batch-processing

So I have an NFT collection that I've created, it's containing 2 different designs in same collection.
So I'd like to merge them together, but their JSON files are colliding.
What I'm looking for is:

- Increase a spesific number on spesific string.
- Delete a line from them all completely.

It looks like this:

```
{
  "dna": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "name": "XXXXX XXXXX #0", ##I'd like to change this number value. I'd like to add 3000 on top of every other one.
  "description": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.",
  "image": "REPLACE-THIS-WITH-YOUR-URL/0.png", #How to replace in batch?
  "date": 1641544983764,
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "xxxx",
      "value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "xxx",
      "value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "xxx",
      "value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "xxx",
      "value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "xxx",
      "value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "xxx",
      "value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "xxx",
      "value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "xxx",
      "value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "xxx",
      "value": "xxx"
    }
  ],
  "compiler": "xxxxxx" ##Delete this line from all
}
```

So there's 10.000 of these files, it's kinda impossible for me to manual edit.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any programming experience? This can be easily accomplished in C#, Python and many other languages.

Comment: Unfortunately so little.

Comment: Unfortunately that is that way to do it quickly. You could get it done by hiring a freelancer on fiverr.com or similar site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic code would be to (1) get a list of all the json files (2) read each file and parse into json object (3) create a new object and make the required changes (4) save the new file. As a side note I would backup all the files before running anything like this. Here is the basic code, you could work with someone who works with C# to implement this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get all the json files
    var jsonPath = @"c:\temp\json";
    var jsonFiles = Directory.GetFiles(jsonPath, "*.json");

    //loop through each file and process according to specs
    foreach(var jsonFile in jsonFiles)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
        var sample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample>(json);
        var sampleNew = new SampleNew();

        sampleNew.dna = sample.dna;
        sampleNew.name = sample.name + " 3000";
        sampleNew.image = sample.image.Replace("oldurl", "newurl");
        sampleNew.date = sample.date;
        sampleNew.attributes = sample.attributes;

        // serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file
        File.Delete(jsonFile);
        File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sampleNew));
    }

            
}    
        public class Attribute
        {
            public string trait_type { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
    
        }
    
        public class Sample
        {
            public string dna { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string image { get; set; }
            public long date { get; set; }
            public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
            public string compiler { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class SampleNew
        {
            public string dna { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string image { get; set; }
            public long date { get; set; }
            public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
        }
```

Time to get your feet wet, or hire someone!

Comment: You da real MVP

Comment: @JackieSparrow - if you end up using this, please accept the answer